# Does any reverting instruction (assert, require, revert, throw, etc) undo ETH transfer?

Tags: exceptions

I have code which transfer the ether to another address. And below that, I have require() condition will be failing. so will that execute the ether transfer or it will not transfer?

```
function ethTransfer(){

  someAddress.transfer(amount);

  require((1==5), 'error');   // ever reverting!!!

}
```

Any idea will be helpful. Thanks

Comment: Does this code even compile??? `1=5` is an assignment, not a boolean expression.  Also, `address` is a key word, so `address.transfer` doesn't look like something which can compile. Please post a working example. Side note: instead of asking the question, you could simply run your code and check the balance of the account.

Comment: I was thinking exactly the same. However, I think perhaps what is actually being asked is more of a conceptual question, rather than a code question: i.e. If a transfer has already been made, do failures further down the codepath cause that transfer to be reverted or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. If you revert within a call frame, all previous actions in that call frame (including sub-call frames) will be reverted.

Answer (score 0):

A part the coding errors in the example code, your question is clear.

Answer: yes they will be transferred executing your transfer instruction. When your require shall be hit, it will revert all done before and the transferring as well.